# How to trigger specific function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
        console.log("triggered");
```

How can I trigger this function from anywhere in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using History.js then use

```
History.pushState(data,title,url);
```

Comment: hm... I want to trigger this function without Hitory.pushState. Because when I open the page the first time there might be already something like: home.html?add  and then it should load the add page